# Get url after redirect Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, instagram

To authenticate on Instagram I need to get an url sent me by Instagram as a redirect. I need to get the redirected url but I obtain ever null.

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=e40f15a90**c89851d8a66&redirect_uri=http://examle.com&response_type=token",

success:function(result,status,xhr){
console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));<---NULL
}

});
```

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible via AJAX – _because_ this is a request in the background, the browser will follow redirects automatically. And therefor, when control gets handed back to your script, there _is_ no `Location` header any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get header info after redirect that would happen as a result of the request. Standard way is to open new child window with auth url ("https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=...response_type=token",
) and retrieve token in redirect url, for example in onready event of `http://examle.com` after that send token to parent window and close popup (child) window.

Recommended Instagram auth is server side, so consider to use it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm making an app mobile and I don't have server. Which url I must consider as a redirect url? @pocheptsov